# 535 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, the request did not meet the criteria to be authenticated successfully

Tags: node.js, azure, nodemailer

I'm trying to send email via nodemailer. And sender email is of microsoft azure. But I'm getting error-response: '535 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, the request did not meet the criteria to be authenticated successfully. Contact your administrator.
MFA is enabled. Also I have generated app password. Can anyone please help me with this issue.
Code snippet to send mail-

```js
var userTransporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: 'smtp.office365.com',
  port: 587,     // secure SMTP
  secure: false,
  auth: {
    user:SENDER_EMAIL,
    pass: SENDER_APP_PASSWORD,
  }
});

    var mailOptions = {
        from: SENDER_EMAIL,
        to: email,
        template: path.join(__dirname, "../public/views/email-verification"),
        context: {
          token: otp,
          email: email,
          url: EMAIL_VERIFICATION_LINK,
          name: user_name
        },
      };
      let mail = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
```

Comment: you solved the problem ?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using 2-step authentication, you will need to create an app password.

Login to your Microsoft account.

1. Security
2. Advanced security options
3. App passwords
4. Create a new app password

```
transp: {
    host: smtp.office365.com,
    port: 587,
    secure: false,
    auth: {
        user: 'user@email.com',
        pass: 'AppPass'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see in your code that you are using **secure: false** field.
Instead of **secure: false** field you can change into **secureConnection: false**.

```js
var userTransporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: 'smtp.office365.com',
  port: 587,     // secure SMTP
  secureConnection: false,
  auth: {
    user:SENDER_EMAIL,
    pass: SENDER_APP_PASSWORD,
  }
});
```

Make sure to check in your `package.json`  file the **"nodemailer" : "*"**  dependency is added, if not make sure to add it.

Comment: I tried with secureConnection: false too. But error is still same